# cifs mount in fstab mounting to a different directory

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I have a cifs mount in `/etc/fstab`

```
//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/tmp  /mnt/drive2/node/student/current/upload-tool/tmp  cifs   uid=48,credentials=/home/myuser/.creds,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm   0       0
```

when I mount it using

```
mount /mnt/drive2/node/student/current/upload-tool/tmp
```

... It mounts it to `/mnt/drive2/node/student/releases/201605251600/docroot/upload-tool/tmp`  instead (mount command output):

```
//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/tmp on /mnt/drive2/node/student/releases/201605251600/docroot/upload-tool/tmp type cifs (rw,mand)
```

`/mnt/drive2/node/student/current/` is a symbolic link to `/mnt/drive2/node/student/releases/201605251600/docroot`

having the symbolic link change and remount is messing with my monitoring which looks for the directory its mounted on to stay consistent.

Is there a way to mount this so the mount command will show the symbolic path?  aka: `/mnt/drive2/node/student/current/upload-tool/tmp`

Comment: Short answer is, you cannot, afaik. The `mount` command always reports the absolute path to the mount point. Maybe you can hack your monitoring solution, what are you using ?

Comment: I am using nimbus, it is monitoring for any new file systems so when the symbolic link changes and the file system is remounted, the old mount disappears according to nimbus.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is of any help, but you might look at doing a 2nd mount with `--bind` to a new fixed name directory.